# PIG UDF to convert tuple to multiple tuple output

Tags: apache-pig, user-defined-functions, udf

I am new to PIG and I am trying to create a UDF which get a tuple and return multiple tuple based on a delimited. So I have written one UDF to read the below data file

```
2012/01/01 Name1 Category1|Category2|Category3
2012/01/01 Name2 Category2|Category3
2012/01/01 Name3 Category1|Category5
```

Basically i am trying to read $2 field

```
Category1|Category2|Category3
Category2|Category3
Category1|Category5
```

to get the output as :-

```
Category1, Category2, Category3
Category2, Category3
Category1, Category5
```

Below is the UDF code i have written..

```
    package com.test.multipleTuple;    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
    import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
    import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;

    public class TupleToMultipleTuple extends EvalFunc<String> {

        @Override
        public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

            // Keep the count of every cell in the
            Tuple aux = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple();

            if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
                return null;
            try {
                String del = "\\|";
                String str = (String) input.get(0);

                String field[] = str.split(del);
                for (String nxt : field) {
                    aux.append(nxt.trim().toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
            }

            return aux.toDelimitedString(",");
        }
    }
```

created Jar --> `TupleToMultipleTuple.jar`

But I am getting the below error while executing it .

```
 Pig Stack Trace
    ---------------
    ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B

    org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:892)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:547)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:884)
        ... 13 more
```

Can you please help me in rectifying the issue. Thanks.

Pig script for applying the UDF..

```
REGISTER TupleToMultipleTuple.jar;
DEFINE myFunc com.test.multipleTuple.TupleToMultipleTuple();
A = load 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(' ');
B = foreach A generate myFunc($2);
dump B;
```

Comment: Please add your pig script.

Comment: @54l3d : Actually this time I was looking to fix my UDF. I will really appreciate if you can help me for the same. And the builtin function flatten(STRSPLIT($2,'[|]',3)) worked absolutely fine. I am trying to figure out on why my code is giving me error while executing the UDF. Thanks .

Comment: @54l3d : I have also added pig script with the main problem, on how I am trying to execute my UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in split function like this:

```
flatten(STRSPLIT($2,'[|]',3))as(cat1:chararray,cat2:chararray,cat3:chararray)
```

and you will get 3 tuples named `cat1`, `cat2` and `cat2` typed as `chararray` and delimited by the current delimiter of the relation which they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue .. Issue was while parsing DayaByteArray to String.. used toString() to fix it

```
package com.test.multipleTuple;    
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
    import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
    import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;

    public class TupleToMultipleTuple extends EvalFunc<String> {

        @Override
        public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

            // Keep the count of every cell in the
            Tuple aux = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple();

            if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
                return null;
            try {
                String del = "\\|";
                String str = (String) input.get(0).toString();

                String field[] = str.split(del);
                for (String nxt : field) {
                    aux.append(nxt.trim().toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
            }

            return aux.toDelimitedString(",");
        }
    }
```